# How test if _ensureIndex is working?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Is there some way to display the index – and see if it is working? Thanks!

I'm building it at startup:

```
// create a compound index
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function() {
        MyPix.files._ensureIndex({'metadata.tags': 1, 'original.name': 1, 'uploadedAt': -1})
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can connect via `meteor mongo`

and then run

```
show collections
```

Select the collection that corresponds to `MyPix`, say it says `mypix`

```
db.mypix.getIndexes();
```

Comment: `show collection` returns the collections `cfs.MyPix.filerecord` and `cfs.tempstore.chunks`and `system.indexes` ––– but (`db.cfs.MyPix.getIndexes()`, `db.cfs.MyPix.files.getIndexes()` or `db.MyPix.getIndexes()`) only show an empty array `[ ]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use mongodb's [getIndexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/list-indexes/) method.

```
meteor mongo
db.files.getIndexes()
```

Or you can use mongodb's cursor [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/).

```
meteor mongo
db.files.find(<query>).explain()
```

Comment: + on using explain which can give more info on what indexes were used for the query

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if any of these are correct, but both seem to return empty Arrays. Does it mean there is not index?

```
meteor:PRIMARY> show collections
cfs.MyPix.filerecord
cfs._tempstore.chunks
system.indexes
meteor:PRIMARY> db.cfs.MyPix.getIndexes()
[ ]
meteor:PRIMARY> db.MyPix.getIndexes()
[ ]
```